# Very simple python cycle string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, cycle

I want to write in a file which changes the name with the counter.

```
for j in range(30):
    fileout.write("bla bla")
```

and `fileout` should be

file001 if j=1

file002 if j=2

...

...

I cannot format it in the right way.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the .zfill( < number of digits > ) option. It will complet your string with 0.

For example, this code should work :

```
radical ='file'                                                                                                                          
numberOfDigits = 3                                                                                                                          

for j in range( 30 ) :                                                                                                                   
    fileout = open ( radical + '%s' %(str(j).zfill(numberOfDigits)) + '.txt' , 'w' )                                                        
    fileout.write('bla bla')                                                                                                             
    fileout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if below means what you needed ?
Code below will create file000 - file029 with 'bla bla' inside

```
for i in range(30):
    with open("file%03d" % i, 'w') as f:
        f.write('bla bla')
```